# Android - How to make UI look same across devices?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, screen, resolution

There is a variety of devices on the market, with different screen sizes, resolutions and pixel density.

What are some layout preferences or tips/tricks that are generally used to make sure the app looks the same across devices?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use the "dip" as standart unity instead of pixels, 
use layout_weight to make proportions

and all my app's are fully compatible to 10 inches tablet devices and small smartphones with 3,2 inches screen!

Comment: Have to say that is an extremely vague answer and not saying very much. What about drawables that you have failed to mention,not alone the different subdirectories used within res to cope with that....?

Comment: Thank a lot for your kind downvote. This man is asking to have the same look and feel over tablets and phones. So, using different layouts will make the app look different!

Answer (score 1):

For a start, you could try positioning and scaling UI elements based of a percentage of the screen (for example, placing a button at 75% of the screen). In other circumstances, for example having a window attached to the right of the screen, just get the width of the screen minus the size of the window and place it there.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you grasp the different between `wrap_content` and `fill_parent` on the layouts. In in elements that are arranged vertically (like a list), you will almost always want `wrap_content` on the height and `fill_parent` on the width. Vice versa for elements arranged hortizontally.

As Profete162 said, always prefer the `dip` unit (it can be thought of as an abstracted pixel size). It helps insure that different resolution-densities don't break your hard-coded widths and heights. Ideally, there should never be a mention of `dip` in your theme code, but what is good in theory is not always pragmatic in practice.

These days, you should never use `px` for the size of something.